# Specify which partition to subscribe to in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Hi so i've been trying to set up a simple kafka consumer in java that looks like this
This thing is it doesn't print anything, but when i start a consumer from PowerShell it also shows nothing unless i specify the --partition 0
So this is what i wanted to do with my code but it doesn't seem to work

```
props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("group.id", "test-group");
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
List<TopicPartition> topics = Arrays.asList(topicPartition);
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
//consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
consumer.assign(topics);
//consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("ToDigestion"));
       while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
              System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n",record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
```

Broker configuration below :

```
broker.id=1
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dir=C:/Users/renek/Desktop/kafka-log
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

**EDIT 1** : consumer.poll(int) is deprecated, it takes a `java.time.Duration` as a param, this still doesn't solve the problem, but a step forward

[Data in the topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjyQs.png)

Comment: Why do you want to use a specific partition? Isn't it easier to subscribe to a topic and let kafka handle the partition assignment?

Comment: That's also what i thought, (the commented lines) but since trying it in console gave me the result i wanted i thought i would do that for my app

Comment: Please provide us broker config (and topic if it exists). Also please update the question with data that topic has already.

Comment: Updated the question (topic n/a)